# GDAL C# Bindings

Tags: gdal, geojson, vector, c#, vector-tiles

I need some help on usage of GDAL C# bindings to convert geoJSON to MVT. How do I know that, below call is complete? We observed that below call is Async (All the code lines are executed and Parent thread is waiting until the MVT files/folders are created in disk). Is this correct?

I want to create a Vector Tile Service. My goal is to return the tile to client once the tiles are generated. For this, I need whether the call is completed or not? Below is the code, written in console app.

```
 var options = new[]
  {
      "-f", "MVT",       
      "-dsco", "TILE_EXTENSION=pbf",       
      "-dsco", "MINZOOM=0",
      "-dsco", "MAXZOOM=10",
};

  string input = @"C:\Temp\sample.json";
  string output = @"C:\Temp\myMVTtiles";

  using (
    Dataset ds = Gdal.OpenEx(input, 4, null, null, null))
  {     
    var newDs = Gdal.wrapper_GDALVectorTranslateDestName (output, ds, gdalOptions, null, null);   
    newDs.FlushCache();     
  }
}
```